# How to identify the Domains and Sub-Domains of a Mainframe Application to calculate the Function Poin of the Application

Tags: cobol, mainframe, boundary, function-points

I am analyzing a Mainframe application and want to calculate the Function Point of said application. I wanted to know from the community what are the conventional ways to Identify the Domain and Sub-Domain of a Mainframe application objectively.

Thanks,
Gustavo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate Function Point of Mainframe applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110403/how-to-calculate-function-point-of-mainframe-applications)

Comment: Hi @guster47 an welcome to SO. I highly suggest to read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and delete the duplicate (I guess you would have liked to edit the previous question but as neither has any answer I suggest to delete the old one this time).